# Bash: How to avoid blank at the beginning of a line?

Tags: linux, bash

Given such a command in bash:

```
echo -e "a b "{1..3}" d e\n"
a b 1 d e
 a b 2 d e
 a b 3 d e
```

the output of line 2... starts with a blank. Why is that? Where does it come from? How can I avoid it?

I do know how to get rid of it with sed or something else, but I would prefer to avoid it in the first place.

I've only mentioned it, together with {..}-Syntax. Are there other, similar cases, without it?

#### update:

A useful workaround is, to remove the first letter with backspace:

```
echo -e "\ba b "{1..3}" d e\n"
```

or, as Jared Ng suggests:

```
echo -e "\ra b "{1..3}" d e\n"
```

#### update 2:

We get rid of leading newlines with:

```
echo -e "\na b "{1..4}" d e" | sed '1d'
echo -e "\na b "{1..4}" d e" | tail -n +2
```

or trailing:

```
echo -e "\ba b "{1..3}" d e\n" | sed '$d'
echo -e "\ba b "{1..3}" d e\n" | head -n 3
```

Comment: Does sh have this problem as well?

Comment: `printf` gives you better control over your output: `printf "%s\n" "a b "{1..3}" d e"`

Comment: Does sh have `{a..n}` at all?

Comment: No, I don't think sh does curly brace expansion.

Comment: Another workaround: `eval "echo 'a b "{1..3}" d e';"`

Comment: @Pumbaa80 That's a nifty solution! It's tricky to figure out, but interesting nonetheless.

Comment: @Jared I've had so much trouble with the limitations of Bash that I've somehow gotten used to `eval`-spamming... However, you need to take great care of escaping. That's why "eval is evil", and I discourage everyone from using it ;) BTW: It's easier to figure out if you replace `eval` by `echo`

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Definitely. I don't encourage the use of `eval` either, but your workaround is an interesting way to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo -e "\ra b "{1..3}" d e\n"
```

Fixes it for me. Output:

```
a b 1 d e
a b 2 d e
a b 3 d e
```

(`\r` is the carriage return -- it brings the caret back to the beginning of the line, preventing the space)

Why does bash do this? Run `echo "abc"{1..3}`. You'll see that bash outputs: abc1 abc2 abc3. Notice the spaces in between? `{1..3}` expands the expression, delimited by spaces. When you use a newline, as in `echo "abc"{1..3}"\n"`, bash keeps those spaces and simply adds a newline as requested. Those are what show up in the output.

Comment: why caret doesn't start at the beginning?

Comment: This does indeed work, but what a wierd solution to a wierd problem. It seems to be part of the way `\n` is interpretted - if you move it to the beginning of the line you get a random space on the end of the output lines...

Comment: Here, this might illustrate why bash has this oddity. Run `echo "abc"{1..3}`. You'll see that bash outputs: `abc1 abc2 abc3`. Notice the spaces in between? When you use a newline `echo "abc"{1..3}"\n", bash keeps those spaces and simply adds a newline as requested. Those are what show up in the output.

Answer (score 4):

The `{...}` expands to a sequence of space-delimited alternatives, so you have in effect

```
echo "a b "1" d e\n" "a b "2" d e\n" "a b "3" d e\n"
```

The spaces after `\n` are the spaces you're seeing in the output.

You can try to move `\n` to the beginning of your string, like in

```
echo -e "\na b "{1..3}" d e"
```

**Update**

Another method (untested, sorry)

```
 printf "%s\n" "a b "{1..3}" d e"
```

Comment: @nm: that isn't very good since there will be an extra line at the beginning of the output

Comment: @Kit Ho: now you have one extra newline at the end (probably avoidable with some extra flags to `echo`).

Comment: The other solutions have the problem at the last line, and deleting the first line is as easy as deleting the last one, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

[Brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) was designed to generate a list of entries to be used as arguments to commands. The generated entries are always space-delimited, hence the extra spaces.

To use the `{1..3}` syntax as is, you'll need to use a command that can treat each generated entry as an independent arg (`echo` simply prints them out as it sees it). A good option here is `printf` (as suggested by @glenn in the comments above).

```
[me@home]$ printf "%s\n" "a b "{1..3}" d e"
a b 1 d e
a b 2 d e
a b 3 d e
```